# От чего зависит репутация на ресурсе?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация

Её понижают потому что я из России? Или я оскорбил кого своими вопросами? Рекламирую что-либо, или нарушаю закон?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: А linux причём?)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/513210/atmos-fear?tab=reputation смотрите тут

Comment: Задал вопрос про опыт использования одного из оборудования для пентеста. Наверное это кого-то оскорбило)) Мне влепили минус к репутации.

Comment: @gil9red возможно, у автора есть удалённые вопросы?

Comment: @andreymal, при удаленных разве рейтинг не возвращается? По-крайней мере, когда пользователей удаляют, то те, кому тот ставил плюсы/принимал ответы рейтинг снижают :)

Comment: Там ссылку выше уже дали, человек снял принятый ответ, за это -2, которые давали за принятие

Comment: "Задал вопрос про опыт использования одного из оборудования для пентест". Такие вопросы у нас оффтопик. Полистайте [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), чтобы потом не расстраиваться.

Comment: @Зонтик вопрос про флиппер был заминусован

Comment: @Nofate но у автора нет такого вопроса... Возможно, он удалён....

Comment: @Зонтик да, автор увидел негативный отклик и удалил его. И вот вопрошает, почему так.

Comment: @Nofate переписал ответ. Хотя, может делать этого и не стоило, но хотелось направить человека на путь истинный....

Answer (score 0):

#### Про минусы

Если за вопрос был дан голос "против", то у вас вычитается два балла репутации. Это неприятно. Но если на вашем вопросе минусы, то это означает, что в вопросе не хватает информации, чтобы вам помочь или вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта.

#### Про вопрос, который сейчас удалён

Поскольку вы удалили вопрос, то то, что у вас забрали минусы, вернулось к вам `=)`. Я не могу просмотреть ваш удалённый вопрос, но если его можно было улучшить, то его удалять не стоило. Если же вопрос не соответствовал тематике сайта, на него нельзя было дать объективный ответ, то вы правильно поступили.

#### На будущие

Старайтесь задавать вопросы, на которые можно дать однозначный и объективный ответ и которые соответствуют тематике сайта. Ознакомьтесь со статьёй в справке [На какие темы можно задвать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Если в вашем вопросе не хватает информации, чтобы дать хороший ответ, то нажмите "править" под вопросом и отредактируйте сообщение, добавляя в него информацию о вашей проблеме и попытках решения. Полезные статьи в справке: [Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Если на вашем вопросе минусы, то это означает, что - *"вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он непонятен или не несёт пользы".*

Comment: Кстати,  вот это правило -- `"Старайтесь задавать вопросы, на которые можно дать однозначный и объективный ответ`" одно из самых дурацких, поскольку для оценки возможности дать такой ответ участниками сайта желательно уже знать ответ на свой вопрос. Безосоновательно предполагая же, что они весьма компетентны, спрашивающий как раз и получает минусы от раздосадованной толпы

Comment: @avp мне кажется вы неправильно его понимаете. Большинство вопросов на ruSO вполне соответствуют этой рекомендации. Давайте перефразируем - `"Старайтесь НЕ задавать вопросы, на которые нельзя дать однозначный или объективный ответ"`. (анти)-примеры "На чем мне писать сайт?", "Посмотрите мой код?", "От чего мой комп тормозит?", "Что лучше, Винда или Убунта?" и т.п.